# Dual monitor - Desktop falls off the screen slightly

Tags: 14.04, multiple-monitors, resolution

I have a dual monitor setup where I have placed a 1280x1024 resolution monitor to the left and a 1920x1080 resolution monitor to the right. Internally it looks like Ubuntu (14.04) changes the total resolution to 3200x1080. So because I have placed the smaller monitor left, where the desktop's icons are oriented towards, the icons fall slightly off the screen. The 56 extra pixels ubuntu created at the bottom of my smaller monitor are filled with content, which obviously isn't visible. I have set "Scale all window contents to match" to the smaller monitor, but that didn't change much. Actually changing that setting doesn't change anything visibly or at least that I could see. So how do I go about changing how ubuntu handles this? Or should I always keep the bigger monitor (in height) to the left as a rule of thumb?

Added screenshot for clarity. For example file11 falls off the screen now.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same problem with multi-monitors and right-click "organize desktop by name".

Some of the icons go off the visible screen and I have to ctrl-A to bring them back into view.

Answer (score -1):

There might be a way to adjust this using your monitor rather than through the OS.

Some monitors have built in "auto-adjust picture" functionality; otherwise, if you just click on the menu button on your monitor, and navigate around, there is probably a way to manually adjust the x-y position of the image.

Comment: The relative position is not a problem, I can change this in the Displays settings too by sliding the monitor up or down relative to the other monitor. If I would slide the left monitor down though to match the bottom of the right monitor, the top will fall off the screen instead of the bottom.